# CodeIgniter can not use PHP's namespace

Tags: php, jwt, codeigniter-3

I'm trying use `firebase/php-jwt` in `CodeIgniter 3`, but I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/kpittu_api/application/controllers/User.php on line 23

this is my code:

```
  require('vendor/autoload.php');
  use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
  $key = "example_key";
  $payload = array(
    "iat" => time(),
    "exp" => time() + 86400,
    "data" => [
      "login" => "sii1995",
      "fname" => "Salim",
      "sname" => "Ibrogimovich",
      "lname" => "Ibrogimov"
    ]
  );
  $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $key);
  $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
  $decoded_array = (array) $decoded;
  /*
  JWT::$leeway = 60; // $leeway in seconds
  $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
  */

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($jwt);
  echo '<hr>';
  print_r($decoded_array);
  echo '</pre>';
```

When I using this code outside `CodeIgniter` it's work well.
How can Use `namespace` / `use` keyword in `CodeIgniter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear friends I solve it: I just need to put these two lines above `class` declarations:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class User extends CI_Controller {
```

Comment: great you did it by own !

Comment: yeah docs are the first thing that you need to read before implementing :)

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid: that's TRUE )